# RichTextBlockOverflow.HasOverflowContent always false in Windows 8 Metro app

Tags: windows-store-apps, richtextblock, richtextblockoverflow

since you have to support multiple screen resolutions in Windows 8 Metro Apps I want to split up my RichTextBlock to show text that would be cut off in a RichTextBlockOverflow control (or multiple controls, depending how much text I have to show).
In order to determine if I have to show an additional RichTextBlockOverflow-Control I check the 
HasOverflowContent-Property of my RichTextBlocks. But it always returns false.

It's super easy to reproduce:

- Create a new "Windows Store -> Blank App"
- Replace the xaml of MainPage.xaml with the following code:

  ```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
      <RichTextBlock x:Name="test1" Width="100" Height="300" OverflowContentTarget="{Binding ElementName=test}">
          <Paragraph>
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
              lkj halks dflkjha skld fkla hsdkl hfakl dsflk hasdkl fakl hsdklf halks dflka jhsdhfklaj hsdklf jhakls dflkaj hsdlkfjh alks dflkajh s
          </Paragraph>
      </RichTextBlock>
      <RichTextBlockOverflow x:Name="test" Width="100" Height="300" />

  </StackPanel>
  ```

Then go the code behind file (MainPage.xaml.cs) and replace the constructor with that code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    if (test.HasOverflowContent)
    {
        // Will never be entered
    }
    if (test1.HasOverflowContent)
    {
        // Will never be entered
    }
}
```

Set a breakpoint in the on this.InitializeComponent() and see how the HasOverflowContent will never be true.

What am I doing wrong? Or is it a bug in .NET?

Any help would be very appreciated ;)

Andi

Comment: You should use Canvas with opacity 0 as in example provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a different event, by putting your code in the `Page_Loaded` event I was able to get `HasOverflowContent` to work.